# ArcPy toolbox - How to limit GPFeatureRecordSetLayer to interactive rectangle input

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, geoprocessing-framework

### The issue

I have an ArcGIS Python Toolbox for which I would like the user to be able to interactively define an oriented rectangular extent (bounding box + rotation) as input parameter.

I currently use a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer

```
arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = "Extent",
    name="extent",
    datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input"
)
```

However, I do not find any way to restrict the input to rectangular geometries. The user can do it by selecting polygon geometry then the rectangle, but I would like all the other options to be hidden and rectangle selected by default.

[image]

Is there any way to do that, or any other way for the user to define a rotated rectangle as input?

### Minimal example

For info, here is a full minimal toolbox (.pyt file) requesting GPFeatureRecordSetLayer input. This example can be imported into ArcGIS pro, leading to the screenshot above:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        params =  [
            arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName = "Extent",
                name="extent",
                datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
                parameterType="Optional",
                direction="Input"
            )
        ]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return

    def postExecute(self, parameters):
        """This method takes place after outputs are processed and
        added to the display."""
        return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict or limit the edit tools for the `GPFeatureRecordSetLayer` with the use of well defined schema layer template.

To create this. either take existing data, or create a new feature class, and start editing. From the **Create Features** pane, right click your template layer, and choose **Properties**. This opens a window like you can see in the below screen shot. Uncheck the tools you do not want to use.

[image]

From the layer in your **Contents** pane, right click and choose **Sharing** > **Save as layer file**. Save to a `.lyrx` somewhere.

In your PYT, add a `.value` to the parameter, refererncing the `lyrx` schema file you've created.

```
param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Just a Box",
        name="extent",
        datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
        parameterType="Optional",
        direction="Input"
    )
param1.value = "C:\\Users\\khibma\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\MyProject3\\polyschema.lyrx"
```

You'll end up with something like:

[image]

Comment: Great solution! I'm guessing the lyrx file should be stored _relative_ to the toolbox script for maximum portability, rather than being squirrelled away in the my documents folder?

Comment: Right, it would be better to keep the `lyrx` relative/beside the PYT. My example just shows the lazy way. This solution applies to all toolboxes; with a "real" tbx, the information from the `lyrx` is actually imported, so you don't actually need to bring the file along for the ride.

Comment: Excellent, it works, thanks! By chance, is there any solution to restrict the layer to a single feature?

Comment: You want the control to only allow someone to create a single feature? You can't do that in the control. You have 2 choices: 1) Use tool validation to throw an error if more than 1 feature is created. 2) In the tool code always just use the first feature and send a warning message during execution that you made that choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is what I ended doing (checking that the layer only contains one feature)